# Why is this valid $tr(VDV^{-1}) = tr(VV^{-1}D)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a diagonalizable matrix A, such that this relation holds:
$A = VDV^{-1} $,
where D is a diagonal matrix.

Now the following relation is given when taking the trace:
$tr(VDV^{-1}) = tr(VV^{-1}D) = tr(ID) = tr(D)$

I'm wondering what's the background which allows you to move D to the right in this relation? : $tr(VDV^{-1}) = tr(VV^{-1}D)$

Comment: That's misleading. Better would be to write $tr(VDV^{-1}) = tr(V^{-1}VD)$. One moves the $V^{-1}$ to the left. The point is that $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$. **But** for products of more than two factors, the trace is not permutation-invariant. You can only move one single factor from the right to the left (or the other way round) at a time.

Comment: hmm is it also possible to say that:
$tr(VDV−1) = tr(V)tr(D)tr(V^{-1}) = tr(V^{-1})tr(V)tr(D) = tr(V^{-1}VD) = tr(ID) =tr(D)$

Since the trace are scalars you can move them around like shown above, but is it legal to split them apart like that (maybe that's not valid)?

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Consider the case where all matrices are the identity, then $tr(I\cdot I\cdot I) = tr(I) = n$, but if you split up, the product of the traces is $n^3$. You have $tr(ABC) = tr(CAB) = tr(BCA)$, but in general $tr(ACB)$ is different (when the product in that order is defined, which it need not be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that $VDV^{-1}$ is similar to $D$, i.e. it has the same eigenvalues, and that the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues (counted with multiplicity). The former statement is easy to prove when $D$ is diagonal: the eigenvectors of $VDV^{-1}$ are the columns of $V$, and you can identify the eigenvalues easily.

The latter statement is a little bit harder to prove. One direct approach is to prove that the coefficient on the linear term in the expansion of the characteristic polynomial is $-T$, which implies that the sum of the roots of the polynomial is $T$.

Much more generally, however, we have $Tr(AB)=Tr(BA)$, which can be read off from the definition of each expression.

Comment: What if $D$ has no eigenvalues?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe A diagonal matrix is diagonalizable: it has a full set of eigenvalues (its diagonal entries) and a full set of eigenvectors (the unit coordinate vectors $e_i$). If $D$ were not diagonal then the approach I suggested first would indeed be somewhat complicated, and the method of the third paragraph would be easier.

Comment: Ups, my stupid mistake.

Comment: Isn't it so that since this is a symmetric matrix, we know that the sum of the diagonal elements of A is equal to the sum of the eigenvalues, but I guess  the operations above is the proof for that statement.

Comment: No symmetry is required for this result. In fact diagonalizability is not required either.